# Hiding empty rows in report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to hide rows in report if they are empty, but I got problem. I made every measure to return `nothing` if empty and cells looks like they were actually empty, but I still can see them. I tried to return `System.DBNull.Value` in place of `nothing`, but rows were still visible.

I know that I can set expression for visibility like that: `iif(expression_for_col1 = 0 or expression_for_col2 = 0 or..., false, true)`, but I got 22 columns, of which some are really complicated and this would slow down report too much.

There is no column groups in my report, just 4 row groups.

Comment: How are you returning nothing? Share the expression for the measure. Did you try `=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!Measure.Value),True,False)`.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta, im doing `iif(Fields!Some_measure.Value = 0, nothing, Fields!Some_measure.Value)`

Comment: @alejandrozuleta or when the measure is calculated in cell it is like `iif((complicated expression)=0, nothing, (complicated expression))`

Comment: Why don't you use the same expression for hiding the row?. `=iif((complicated expression)=0, True, False)`.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I don't want to hide empty cells, but whole row, that has only empty cells. If I set this expression for every single cell, it is only hiding cells, but row groups are still visible. If I want to do this for whole row, the expression would be really really long as it'd consist of 23 field's expressions and it'd be really hard to change something or debug if needed. I know it is possible, but I want to avoid this way.

Comment: Select the whole row, right click it and go to Row Visibility property, use the expression to conditionally hide the row.